# Color flashcards with flashcards document class

Tags: backgrounds, contour, flashcards

I would like to specify the background (or border) color of a flashcard with the "flashcard" document class, how can I do that?

Here a minimal exemple:

```
\documentclass[testpage,grid]{flashcards}

\renewcommand{\cardfrontheadstyle}[2][]
{\renewcommand{\flashcards@ps@front@head}
{\csname \flashcards@ps@front@head@#2\endcsname}
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{%
\renewcommand{\flashcards@format@front@head}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

% ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ %
%               Flashcard                %
% ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ %
\cardfrontfoot{Acide/Base}
\begin{flashcard}[Savoir]{Donner la définition d'un acide}
Un acide AH est une espèce chimique capable de libérer un proton. 
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean the `flashcard` document class? Note that there exists also the `flashcards` class ...

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean `flashcard` document class

Comment: @AlexandreFafin Please add a small, but compilable test document to your question (... and you might want to edit your title as well)

Comment: Welcome. // Looks like color is not provided ... so you have to code it yourself. // However, if you want these flashcards for learning, there's a more effective approach: Anki. Downloads: https://apps.ankiweb.net/#download Use for free, unless you come from the iOS world (then you still can use the online access for free).

Comment: Well, you originally said that you used the `flashcard` document class (without the "s", and I explicitly asked you whether it is the one with or without "s"), so my first answer is based on the this package. Apart from that, you need to add an option to define the size of the cards, such as `avery5371`. Without this, your MWE is not compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP originally asked for the `flashcard` document class, which is why I came up with an answer for that.

I hope that this won't break anything, but you should be able to patch the package like this (the example is taken from the package code):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{flashcard}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\FC@nopadfbox}[1]{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\colorbox{flashcardbgcolor}{#1}}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\flashcardformat}{\centering\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\flashcardbackword}{Solution}
\flashcardtopic{The Holy Grail}

\begin{document}
\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{yellow}%
\flashcard{Who rescues Sir Galahad from the Castle Anthrax?}{Sir
Lancelot}
\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{orange}%
\flashcard[Ni!]{What is the one word the Knights of Ni can't hear?}{It}
\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{cyan}%
\flashcard[][Credits]{What once bit the narrator's sister?}{A Moose}
\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{green}%
\flashcard{How does King Arthur defeat the killer rabbit?}{Uses the Holy
Hand Grenade of Antioch}
\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{white}%
\end{document}
```

[image] [image]

Coloring the border is more complicated, but also possible:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{flashcard}

\usepackage{etoolbox, xcolor}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\FC@nopadfbox}[1]{\fboxsep=0pt\color{flashcardbordercolor}\fbox{\colorbox{flashcardbgcolor}{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\FC@pvbox}[1]{\fboxsep=2pt\fboxrule=0pt\color{flashcardbordercolor}\fbox{\vbox{\color{flashcardtextcolor}#1}}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\flashcardformat}{\centering\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\flashcardbackword}{Solution}
\flashcardtopic{The Holy Grail}

\colorlet{flashcardbordercolor}{red}
\colorlet{flashcardtextcolor}{black}

\begin{document}
\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{yellow}%
\flashcard{Who rescues Sir Galahad from the Castle Anthrax?}{Sir
Lancelot}
\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{orange}%
\flashcard[Ni!]{What is the one word the Knights of Ni can't hear?}{It}
\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{cyan}%
\flashcard[][Credits]{What once bit the narrator's sister?}{A Moose}
\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{green}%
\flashcard{How does King Arthur defeat the killer rabbit?}{Uses the Holy
Hand Grenade of Antioch}
\colorlet{flashcardbordercolor}{blue}%
\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{white}%
\end{document}
```

[image] [image]

---

For the `flashcards` document class, you can probably make use of the same logic. Since there is only one `\fbox` used, you could replace this by `\fcolorbox` which is provided by the `xcolor` package (note that for some reason the empty boxes are somehow drawn twice which is, however, not an error introduced by this patch but rather a bug in the package in general):

```
\documentclass[testpage,grid,avery5371]{flashcards}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\flashcards@gridbox}[1]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0in}\fcolorbox{flashcardbordercolor}{flashcardbgcolor}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\colorlet{flashcardbgcolor}{yellow}
\colorlet{flashcardbordercolor}{red}

\cardfrontfoot{Acide/Base}
\begin{flashcard}[Savoir]{Donner la définition d'un acide}
Un acide AH est une espèce chimique capable de libérer un proton. 
\end{flashcard}
\end{document}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect!!

Comment: Obviously, it is not perfect, considering the downvote ... As I said, handle this with care. I did not test this extensively.